# Python - socketserver & sqlite3: Can't put messages into the database

Tags: python, sqlite, socketserver

I have been facing trouble where I could not put the data sent through the server to the database. I used the python's socketserver and sqlite3 class as the server and the database.

Here's my code:

```
    import socketserver
    import sqlite3

    conn = sqlite3.connect('messages.db', check_same_thread=False)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messagesTable(msg BLOB)')

    class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):

        def handle(self):
            # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
            print(self.client_address[0]) #the client's ip
            print(self.data)
            # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
            self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

        def put_database(self):
            c.execute("INSERT INTO messagesTable(msg) VALUES(?)", self.data)
            conn.commit()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        HOST, PORT = "localhost", 8888

        # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 8888
        server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
        database = MyTCPHandler.put_database()
        server.serve_forever()
```

It's sending messages well, from the client side, and managed to send back the correct data which convinces me that the server is working properly at least. However, it seems that the data is not written into the database messages.db
I am new to python and help is much needed. Is there anything wrong with my script or any adjustments that I have to make? Thank you.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling the put_database method anywhere.

Comment: I've updated it, can you take a look ?

Comment: Well that doesn't make sense, surely you need to call it when you actually receive data?

Comment: So, I put it on the handle method ?

Comment: if you want things to happen in response to messages, then yes, you need your code to trigger when a message comes in.